# change the name of a kendo grid Excel file asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, excel, kendo-ui, datepicker, kendo-grid

I am working with asp.net MVC Kendo UI. I am using Kendo grid to excel. 
I have a datepicker to filter the grid information according to the date.

everything works fine, but I need to change the name of the Excel file to:

> X_(datepicker).xlsx

my code is:

```
.Excel(excel => excel
            .FileName("X_" + ..... + ".xlsx")
            .Filterable(true)
            .ProxyURL(Url.Action("Excel_Export_Save", "X"))
            .AllPages(true)
        )
```

javascript to get the Kendo datepicker name :

```
function getDatePicker() {
        return kendo.toString($("#datepicker").data("kendoDatePicker").value(), "dd.MM.yyyy");
    }
```

how to put the value of the datepicker instead of the "....."?

P.S. the datepicker is outside the Kendo grid.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`excelExport`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#events-excelExport) event to set `e.workbook.fileName`, according to your preferences.

```
function excelExport(e) {
  e.workbook.fileName = "X_" + getDatePicker() + ".xlsx";
}
```